# Are there any hidden (i.e., OOB) collectibles in Donkey Kong 64 in addition to Diddy's Jungle Japes banana?

Tags: donkey-kong-64

In Jungle Japes, Diddy Kong has an extra Red Banana located out of bounds.

Are there any other "extra" collectible items in the game; bananas, banana coins, etc. (excluding the well known methods of golden banana duping)?

Comment: @Timelord64 This appears to be an extra red banana that's located outside the bounds of the level, normally not collectable. The counter isn't moving up past the normal 100 maximum, even when it's not the last banana collected (shown in clip 2).

Comment: Ahh I see it. Thats really hard to tell, though. This question could still use clarification